# How can you write a power Enum with visitor semantics in Scala?

Tags: scala, enumeration, visitor-pattern

There is a pattern I use often to make code simpler that I like to call a Power Enum which is an enumeration that takes advantage of the visitor pattern as well as carries custom data. Here is an example in Java:

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class PowerEnumDemo {
    private static final SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3 ; i++) {
            final Color selected = Color.values()[random.nextInt(3)];
            System.out.println("Selected: " + selected);
            System.out.println("rgb: " + selected.rgb);
            selected.visit();
        }
    }

    public enum Color {
        RED("0000ff") {
            @Override
            public void visit() {
                IntStream.range(1, 10).forEach(System.out::println);
            }
        },
        GREEN("00ff00") {
            @Override
            public void visit() {
                System.out.println(UUID.randomUUID().toString().chars().filter(c -> c == 'a').count());
                ;
            }
        },
        BLUE("ff0000") {
            @Override
            public void visit() {
                System.out.println("Hello World");
            }
        };
        final String rgb;

        Color(final String rgb) {
            this.rgb = rgb;
        }

        /**
         * This is where the enum implements the visitor pattern to do special stuff.
         */
        public abstract void visit();
    }
}
```

If one runs this little program you will see how it works. We don't have to know which Enum is selected and we don't have to do any if loops which can be annoying to maintain. If a dev adds a new enum they have to define its data and implement the visit method or the code wont compile. But when they do it will work for everyone calling visit.

I want to implement this in Scala but I am at a loss of how to proceed. Here is the proscribed method of creating an enum which is a tad obscure:

```
object Color extends Enumeration{
  type Color = Value
  val RED, GREEN, BLUE = Value
}
```

What I don't see is how I can define my custom data and my abstract visit method and have each val implement the visit method. (for those that don't get it in the java example each enum is kind of a subtype of the main Color enum.) So any of you scala gurus can get this working? :-)

Comment: several alternatives to the scala enum described at http://pedrorijo.com/blog/scala-enums/ and http://pedrorijo.com/blog/scala-enums-part2/ . hope it helps

Comment: That would be great if it came about. I just commented on the issue. Still would be nice to know what to do in the meantime.

Comment: There is nothing related to the visitor pattern here. It's just a run-of-the-mill subclassing with specific behavior definitions by the means of method overriding. You can either stick to vanilla sealed traits or use enumeratum (https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum). Also, could you perhaps edit/rephrase the question so it doesn't refer to the visitor pattern? This will significantly reduce confusion among people answering as well as those who will search for something similar.

Comment: @RobertSimmonsJr. No, it is not. First of all, visitor pattern is about two sides, receiver and visitor. Visitor gets the receiver as a parameter, so overloading `visit` with arguments of different types we can effectively get a dynamic dispatch based not on one, but on two types: visitor's and receiver's (*double dispatch*). The code in question just defines different behaviors in subclasses. Your question is actually just about defining methods on enums and has nothing to do with patterns. Clear questions get clear answers.

Comment: But aside from terminology - check out enumeratum (link above). It has everything you want, including an analog to calling `Enum#values`.

Answer (score 5):

For enums in Scala I would go with sealed traits instead of the `Enumeration` class. Especially for use cases like this.

```
sealed trait Color {
  def visit: Unit
  def rgb: String
}
object Color {
  case object RED extends Color {
    def visit = println("Hello World!")
    val rgb = "ff0000"
  }
  ....
}
```

Comment: That is what I ended up doing but wanted to know if there is a better way. Obviously this lacks many of the facets of an enumeration like being able to say Color.values().